# map not showing in gmaps4rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I'm pretty new to java (and programming in general), and am having a tough time getting the map to show in my production environment.  On my development machine, everything is good, and works well, but when I deploy, the map just won't show.

I did the bundle install, added the gmaps4rails.js file, and included the config.serve_static_assets = true
to the production.rb

Any help or suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: do you have something in your logs? Is there a js error when you load the page?

Comment: Yeah - ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `enable_js' for #<#<Class:0x7f24987c3ad0>:0x7f249$

Comment: Interesting, never had that before. It's param in the helper method. Could you 1) what you have in the view 2)tell me which ruby you use.

Comment: rails -v 3.0.5    <%= gmaps4rails(@json) %>

Comment: That's fine... And which version of ruby?

Comment: ruby 1.8.7 I also tried using this code in the view:

Comment: I just can't understand what is happening there. PLease post the code you have in your view.

Comment: could it be one of the javascript includes?

Comment: TypeError: Result of expression 'google.maps' [undefined] is not an object.

Comment: Js error and template error are different. To be sure it's not the js error, run ‘rails generate gmaps4rails:install‘

Comment: Could not find generator gmaps4rails:install.

Comment: and in my gemfile: gem 'gmaps4rails', '0.7.7'

Comment: You're welcome :) update your gem to the latest version: 0.8.8

Comment: Ah! I post a short answer then, please mark it as good :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long search:

Just needed to update the gem to latest version :)

Comment: Yep - The old gem worked on dev box, and the new one for production.